# Provide security between two web applications

Tags: session, authentication, web

I have an application A where I log in normally and after this login the user can access another application B but application B has no authentication. My problem is that the user can access application B directly without credentials. How do I get my B application to use the same authenticated session from application A.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cookies. When user logs in in A then a cookie is stored and B checks if the cookie is set and which content it has and opens a new session.